# Using Erdős–Szekeres theorem for graph with 50 vertices

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a graph with $50$ vertices such that for every $4$ vertices there are $2$ that have no edge between them (independent).
I want to prove that $G$ has a group of $5$ independent vertices.
**My proof:**
Using Erdős–Szekeres theorem I know that $R(4,5)\leq 35$ so I can take $K_{50}$ (full graph with 50 vertices) and to color all edges of $G$ in blue, the rest in red.
Since there cant be clique of 4 in blue, I know that there has to be a clique of 5 in red.
Is the logic here right?

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.